# How should I show specific data not all data from database?

Tags: codeigniter

I had met a basic problem that i want to show specific ‘account’ not all account data from database.

Just like the pic **[Here](http://ellislab.com/?ACT=33&fid=49&aid=16429_9B4SZ7MK8EhZwpGybleE&board_id=1)**, If the user’s account is *'chiquitta'*

When user need to edit her account setting

It should only show her account information not all of the account information from database.

I had try to solve this problem but it still show all account ~
Did I miss something?

[my controller]

```
function index($id = false)
 {
  $data['page_title'] = lang('admins');
  $data['admins']  = $this->auth->get_admin_specific($id);
  $this->load->view($this->config->item('admin_folder').'/admins', $data);
 }
```

[my model]

```
function get_admin_specific($id)
 {
  $this->CI->db->select('*');

  if ($id)
  {
  $this->CI->db->where('id', $id);
  }

  $result = $this->CI->db->get('admin');
  $result = $result->result();

  return $result;
 }
```

[my view]

```
<?php foreach ($admins as $admin):?>
<?php echo $admin->account; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi what do you mean with 'It should only show her account information not all of the account information from database.'? Some fields?

Well if you want to take data form a single user you can do it like this

```
function get_id($where){
    $this->db->where($where);
    return $this->db->get($this->_table)->row();
}
```

Set your custom array for $where so it search the only row with the id you are looking. Then in your controller:

```
$data['result'] = $this->your_model->get_id(array('id'=>$id));
$this->load->view('youview', $data);
```

Then you can access your data within your view with:

```
$result->field_name;
```

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how to pass the id through the url for the user I want to display.
I want to display the current account , not like a super admin can see all of the account.

Comment: You can pass the id throught the url inside a link then when the user click that link you can get the id by the segment of the uri. For example lets say you have url like this: mysite.com/edit_profile/7 so $this->uri->segment(2) will give you '7'. Also you may use sessions. When  the user log in you set the user_id inside session then you can get more control about what users can do.

I hope I've explained well...sorry my english!